Tomcat and Java Servlet Getting 404
Issue:
I am trying use the html form to make a get request to my java servlet but I am getting a 404 error.
I have tried changing the path from the action tag to /Main and /Assignment9Test/Main and neither are working. When I run the Java servlet it shows as http://localhost:8080/Assignment9Test/Main3.java and shows the servlet code in the browser
Endpoint I am trying to reach : http://localhost:8080/Assignment9Test/Main3?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3
Error - HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
File Structure

Main.html
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; ">
<title>A Sample form using GET</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#fdf5e6">
<center>
<h2>Collecting Three Parameters</h2>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/Assignment9Test/Main3" method="get">
First Parameter&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:
<input type="text" name="param1"><br>
Second Parameter: <input type="text" name="param2"><br>
Third Parameter&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:
<input type="text" name="param3"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>

web.xml
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>Assignment9Test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

Main.java
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/Main3")
public class Main extends HttpServlet {
static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public Main() {
    super();
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
//String title = "Reading Three Request Parameters";
//out.println(
//"<html>\n" +
//"<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
//"<body bgcolor=\"#ff5e6\">\n" +
//"<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
//"<ul>\n" +
//" <li><b>param1</b>: " + request.getParameter("param1") + "\n" +
//" <li><b>param2</b>: " + request.getParameter("param2") + "\n" +
//" <li><b>param3</b>: " + request.getParameter("param3") + "\n" +
//"</ul>\n" +
//"</body></html>");
}
}


You have invalid project structure. The WebContent folder should be in the root of the project. It should also be assigned as web content root folder of the dynamic web project. Don't mess it with the src and java code in it because it is a source for java files. You should restructure your project or create a new one with the eclipse default structure. Or, if you use Maven plugin then with the Maven's  folders structure.
If you need help the you can read How to create a dynamic web project in Eclipse. If you choose a Maven for your project structure then you should read How to convert a Maven web project to Eclipse

The welcome file is needed if you want to specify the url address to the folder which contains a welcome file and this address isn't mapped to the servlet. The Tomcat server has a default servlet which handles a welcome file. It has also a default web.xml where the files you specified are already used by this servlet. So, you can just remove them.

Also even if the <form> tag allowes to specify an absolute url to the website, in your case you submit the form to localhost, and can omit the parts of the url, such as a scheme, hostname, and use uri to the resource.
If you use a relative address then you don't need to specify a full path as it's taken from the base. In the action attribute you can use action="Main3".
